# Importing plain javascript libraries in an AngularJs application

Tags: javascript, libraries, github, angularjs

I am working on an AngularJs project which is getting bigger very fast.

Currently I need to store some user data, so I was using [`$localStorage` for Angular](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage).

But I had a problem, as the application is saving a big amount of data, it is hanging the browser some seconds which is very annoying.

Searching for asynchronous uses of `localStorage` I've found a bunch of people saying that it not possible to use it. But I managed to found some plain javascript implementations on GitHub:

- [localForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) - by Mozilla
- [Async Local Storage](https://github.com/slightlyoff/async-local-storage) - by a guy who works at Google

There is an [Angular implementation](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage) which is based on what Mozilla provides, but the build is failing and I want to use something more stable due to the importance of the project.

Then I came to this doubt, how should I use plain/vanilla javascript inside an Angular app?

I know that it is discouraged to use jQuery in the way people normally are "tempted" to use. How should I organize my pure javascript libraries in my application in a way that I can still see it very organized and fitting in the "Angular Way"?

**EDIT:** *I know I have given you a fairly specific example about my data storage problem and some people might want help me with this, I really appreciate that (seriously). But unfortunately this is not the kind of answer I expect, since it does not have any relation with my **real question**. Please consider that even if I solve my data problem on my own, I will still want to know what are the best practices of including plain javascript code on my Angular Apps (that's the reason I've posted it here and not in StackOverflow). I could not find any good articles or questions here about it. I want the power of thinking of all great developers out there to help me, but most of all, help the community. I really think that good answers to this question could help a great amount of people, and that is what StackExchange is all about.*

Comment: If localStorage is taking too long, then I'd safe offload most of the storage to the server, and limit localtStorage to a cache.

Comment: The problem is that there a big client side object, which the view is based on. Basically we are building a dynamically created visualization from a given json file. The user can change the inputs the json has and we want to save all modifications the user might do to this data client side, before sending any data forward.

Comment: Consider using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), it is meant for larger data-sizes and works asynchronously. Also note that LocalStorage has a, sometimes unknown max-limit, which is quite low.

Comment: As far as I know, localForage is using IndexedDB inside (at least it gives me an error if I don't include indexeddb.js). But that was just the example I had to give to elaborate **my real question**, try to focus on answering *that* please.

Comment: Sorry I'm still failing to understand what your "real question" is. Is it about how to organize large Angular projects in general?
What do you mean is "including plain javascript code on my Angular Apps" 
Are your controllers not written in "plain javascript"?

Comment: No problem, maybe I was not clear enough on the first time. Not that general, is how is the proper way to incluce and organize plain javascript libraries on Angular projects.

Comment: Without using bower?

Comment: When I put some vanilla javascript in my application it feels a little dirty to me. I want to know if there is proper way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I am not using bower at this time. I'll give it a try someday...

Comment: Then you really should as it solves dependencies for you. (if you include one lib that depends on another the other will also get included).
There are many different ways to go about organizing large projects, it's a lot about taste and personal pref. This means that there is not A BEST way. Everyone can only give you their opinion... starting a huge discussion. I'm not sure Stack Exchange is for that. But I'm not an expert.

Comment: I agree. I did not want to create a discussion here, I just thought there are probably some best practices to follow and I want to know about them.

Comment: So when you say "how should I use plain/vanilla javascript inside an Angular app" - you mean "how to use JS libs outside of angularJS app/scope", e.g. include additional script tags with jQuery etc? AngularJS _is_ a plain JS, after all.

Answer (score 1):

You might like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/). I don't believe there is a "standard Angular way" of importing code because they figure you'll use any of the other techniques:

- Concatenate and minify using Bower
- Import using regular `script` tags
- Use a loading library like Require.js
- Just define your own stuff as services in Angular

You also might want to read http://oblongmana.com/articles/angular-third-party-injection-pattern/ as it describes a pattern for Angularizing third party libraries, which are just plain old JavaScript.